# Group alias of namespaces for controllers

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

Can we group the namespaces `using directive` for all controllers in one file? something like `_imports.razor`. I searched in the internet but I couldn't find an example!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#global-using-directives

Comment: @Oliver, Thanks for your answer, it looks that in preview yest!

Comment: Do you have another option?

Comment: Unfortunately not.